# Aligning 3 columns in LaTeX eqnarray

Tags: equations

I have the following LaTeX eqnarray:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    \int ( D \frac{d^2 P(x)}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}[u(x)P(x)] ) & = & \int 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
    D \frac{d}{dx} P(x) - u(x)P(x) & = & C \Leftrightarrow \\
    D \frac{d}{dx} P(x) - K_0P(x) - \frac{K_1}{x}P(x) & = & C \Leftrightarrow \\
    \frac{dP(x)}{dx} - k_0P(x) - \frac{k_1}{x} P(x) & = & C,
\end{eqnarray}
```

With this outcome:

[image]

Is it possible to align my `\Leftrightarrow` in a 3rd column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should avoid `eqnarray`. See [\eqnarray vs \align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196).

I'd recommend using `align` or `alignat` from `amsmath` package:

[image]

Both `align` and `alignat` provide *pairs* of `rl` alignment columns. So, I used a `&&` before the `\Leftrightarrow` assuming that the next column was to be `r`ight aligned.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}\noindent
Using \verb|align|:
 \begin{align}
    \int ( D \frac{d^2 P(x)}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}[u(x)P(x)] ) &= \int 0 &&\Leftrightarrow \\
    D \frac{d}{dx} P(x) - u(x)P(x)                          &= C      &&\Leftrightarrow \\
    D \frac{d}{dx} P(x) - K_0P(x) - \frac{K_1}{x}P(x)       &= C      &&\Leftrightarrow \\
    \frac{dP(x)}{dx} - k_0P(x) - \frac{k_1}{x} P(x)         &= C,
\end{align}
Using \verb|alignat|:
 \begin{alignat}{4}
    \int ( D \frac{d^2 P(x)}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}[u(x)P(x)] ) &= \int 0 &&\Leftrightarrow \\
    D \frac{d}{dx} P(x) - u(x)P(x)                          &= C      &&\Leftrightarrow \\
    D \frac{d}{dx} P(x) - K_0P(x) - \frac{K_1}{x}P(x)       &= C      &&\Leftrightarrow \\
    \frac{dP(x)}{dx} - k_0P(x) - \frac{k_1}{x} P(x)         &= C,
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The equationarray doesn't allow more than 3 columns, but you can get what you want with the array environment.

```
\[
   \begin{array}{cccc}
      \int ( D \frac{d^2 P(x)}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}[u(x)P(x)] ) & = & \int 0 & \Leftrightarrow \\
      D\frac{d}{dx} P(x) - u(x)P(x) & = & C & \Leftrightarrow \\
      D\frac{d}{dx} P(x) - K_0P(x) - \frac{K_1}{x}P(x) & = & C & \Leftrightarrow \\
      \frac{dP(x)}{dx} - k_0P(x) - \frac{k_1}{x} P(x) & = & C &,
   \end{array}
\]
```

[image: result]

If you dont like the alignment obtained you can modify it for example replacing `{cccc}` with `{rclr}`, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. That does it. But now the lines are interpreted as text lines (with smaller fractions, integrals, etc.) - is there a way to change it to normal? I know I could use dfrac but how about the integrals?

Comment: I just edited. Now you can avoid \dfrac.

Comment: `array` for equations is just a written-out form of the mistakes of `eqnarray` — use the `amsmath` environments mentioned in Peter Grill’s answer.